# Query HIVE table in pyspark

Tags: hive, pyspark

I am using CDH5.5

I have a table created in HIVE default database and able to query it from the HIVE command.

Output

```
hive> use default;

OK

Time taken: 0.582 seconds


hive> show tables;

OK

bank
Time taken: 0.341 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select count(*) from bank;

OK

542

Time taken: 64.961 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

However, I am unable to query the table from pyspark as it cannot recognize the table.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)


sqlContext.sql("use default")

DataFrame[result: string]

sqlContext.sql("show tables").show()

+---------+-----------+

|tableName|isTemporary|

+---------+-----------+

+---------+-----------+


sqlContext.sql("FROM bank SELECT count(*)")

16/03/16 20:12:13 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: FROM bank SELECT count(*)
16/03/16 20:12:13 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 552, in sql
      return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",   line 538, in __call__
    File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 40, in deco
      raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1])
  **pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: no such table bank; line 1 pos 5**
```

***New Error***

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
>>> hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
>>> bank = hive_context.table("default.bank")
16/03/22 18:33:30 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
16/03/22 18:33:30 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
16/03/22 18:33:44 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/22 18:33:44 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/22 18:33:48 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/22 18:33:48 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
16/03/22 18:33:50 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 565, in table
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.table(tableName), self)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 36, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.table.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(ClientInterface.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(ClientInterface.scala:123)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$class.getTable(ClientInterface.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.getTable(ClientWrapper.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:203)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$class.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$1.lookupRelation(HiveContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.table(SQLContext.scala:739)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.table(SQLContext.scala:735)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

thanks

Answer (score 51):

We cannot pass the Hive table name directly to Hive context sql method since it doesn't understand the Hive table name. One way to read Hive table in pyspark shell is:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
bank = hive_context.table("default.bank")
bank.show()
```

To run the SQL on the hive table:
First, we need to register the data frame we get from reading the hive table.
Then we can run the SQL query.

```
bank.registerTempTable("bank_temp")
hive_context.sql("select * from bank_temp").show()
```

Comment: bank = hive_context.table("bank")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 565, in table
 return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.table(tableName), self)File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 36, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.table.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the database name. It should work now.

Comment: hi Bijay697, I am getting error org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException. I updated the error in my original post (under new error). Is there any special config needed to access to HIVE Metastore?

Comment: The error message means the table is no present in the Hive. Can you try creating a table in another database instead of default in a Hive. Also, if you are submitting your job in cluster mode you may need to pass hive-site.xml.

Comment: What is 'sc' in your example above?

Comment: @Sledge that is the SparkContext, a default variable in the session

Comment: when the sql query is multiline, I get `ParseException: u'\nmismatched input \'nodeinv\' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 5)`

Comment: @bijay697 I tried executing the above query in pyspark but it failed with below given error. Can you please help

pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':"

Answer (score 15):

SparkSQL gets shipped with its own metastore (derby), so that it can work even if hive is not installed on the system.This is the default mode.

In the above question, you created a table in hive. You get the `table not found` error because SparkSQL is using its default metastore which doesn't have metadata of your hive table.

If you want SparkSQL to use the hive metastore instead and access hive tables, then you have to add `hive-site.xml` in spark conf folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "spark conf folder" ? Anything specific to mention if pyspark is ran in a Zeppelin application ?

Answer (score 4):

Solution to my problem was to, `cp` the hive-site.xml to your `$SPARK_HOME/conf`, and `cp` the mysql-connect-java-*.jar to your `$SPARK_HOME/jars`, this solution solved my problem.

Comment: Even this worked for me. But I need to know how can I do it programatically without copying hive-site.xml to spark's conf directory

Answer (score 1):

This is how I initialised `sc` to get the hive table records and not just the metadata of it

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext     
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client")     
sc = SparkContext(conf =conf)      
from pyspark import HiveContext      
hive_context=HiveContext(sc)      
data=hive_context.table("database_name.table_name")     
data.registerTempTable("temp_table_name")     
hive_context.sql("select * from temp_table_name limit 10").show()
```

Answer (score -8):

you can use `sqlCtx.sql`. The `hive-site.xml` should be copied to spark conf path.

```
my_dataframe = sqlCtx.sql("Select * from categories")
my_dataframe.show()
```