# How Can use pyspark in zeppelin for HIVE data

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am learning Hadoop environment and sorry if these are such silly questions!

I stored data(Kaggle Outbrain click prediction) to `HIVE`, and I used RDD. 
Then I want to use Zeppelin `spark2.pyspark.` to use python functions.

When I call data with `%jdbc(hive)` I can see it.

My questions are;

How can I make a dataframe to play on the zeppelin or Do I have to create a dataframe?

How can I start python analysis part? If I make any changing will affect HIVE data?

Comment: Hi, you can connect hive through spark / pyspark. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051091/query-hive-table-in-pyspark 

Then, you can create tempTable or RDD for spark